# Is there a cost to inlining a constant Set declaration?

Tags: java, kotlin

Say I have the following Kotlin code:

```
fun isBlue(color: String) = color in setOf("blue", "aqua", "cerulean", "navy", "turquoise")
```

Does declaring the Set in the function body incur a cost of Set creation every time that function runs, or can that be optimized?

Should this be the following instead?

```
private val BLUE_COLORS = setOf("blue", "aqua", "cerulean", "navy", "turquoise")
fun isBlue(color: String) = color in BLUE_COLORS
```

(I'm also interested in whether or not the equivalent Java code also incurs a cost every time)

Comment: This is a very minimal optimisation, but yes using a constant will make the instantiation and initialization only once, at class loading time, while in the function it will be done for each call

Comment: Same in Java: method local variables are created and initialized on every invocation; there's no way around it (like `static` locals in C or C++)

Comment: Yes, both Kotlin and Java will initialize the set every time unless you pull it out into a constant.  A `when` statement with multiple options would do better, however, or a `switch` in Java.

Comment: Note: if that method is called "often enough" the jit will optimize it to machine code anyway. If not, why do you think it is worth optimizing?!

Answer (score 2):

### Naive reasoning.

`setOf( vararg )` call makes two collection allocations:

1. `Array` for vararg
2. `LinkedHashSet`

```kotlin
private val BLUE_COLORS = setOf("blue", "aqua", "cerulean", "navy", "turquoise")
fun isBlue(color: String) = color in BLUE_COLORS
```

Should be *better* as we don't have a `setOf` call every time invoking `isBlue`, but have a single call to init.

### Not that naive.

It depends on target platform and runtime.
`setOf()` is a pure, side effect-free function, so it's a good target for optimizations

#### JVM

It depends on application profile.
Based on profile JIT compiler will (de)optimize this code block.

What could happen:

- inlining
- outlining
- optimizations based on branch prediction [read more](https://advancedweb.hu/jvm-jit-optimization-techniques/)

So effectively compilers are clever and it's unlikely you will see any differences at runtime

#### Android

Android has an extra dimension - APK size. Together with `kotlinc` DX/D8/R8/Proguard/Redex will shrink, optimize, and obfuscate your application code.

Again, at runtime your code will be way different.

- [More](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ_yK8kRCaA&vl=en) about D8/R8
- [More](https://fbredex.com/docs/passes) about Redex optimizations
- [More](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) about Android shrinkers

### tl;dr

Make your decision based on project/company coding conventions.
Use whatever is easier for you to debug, if conventions are flexible in this case.